# Connecting to Websphere MQ Queue with Ruby for testing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ibm-mq

I have been looking into the RubyWMQ gem trying to connect to a Websphere queue, but am having no luck. My ultimate goal is to connect to, read and put messages to the queue using Ruby. I have used the gem authors documentation and examples [here](http://rubywmq.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/WMQ/QueueManager.html#M000015) with no luck as well. currently I have tried this:

```
queue = WMQ::QueueManager.connect(                        
  :q_mgr_name => 'MYQUEUEMANAGERNAMEHERE',
  :exception_on_error => true,
  :trace_level => 2,
  # :connect_options => WMQ::MQCNO_FASTBATH_BINDING,  # this errors
  :channel_name => 'MYQUEUEMANAGERNAMEHERE',
  :connection_name => 'localhost(1414)',
  :transport_type => WMQ::MQXPT_TCP,
  :user_identifier => 'MYUSERNAMEHERE',
  :password => 'MYPASSWORDHERE')
```

I believe the first error I am receiving has to do with the Webshpere MQ client itself, or the install of the gem. i installed RubyWMQ using this command:

```
gem install rubywmq --platform=ruby -- '--with-mqm-include="C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphereMQ\tools\c\include"'
```

I am using IBM WebSphere MQ version 7.1.0.3, located in C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ...

I get this error when running my code:

```
WMQ::QueueManager#connect(). Failed to load MQ Library:mqic32, rc=126 (WMQ::WMQException)
```

I can see the "mqic32.dll" file in C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin, so I am not sure exactly what the gem code is doing..

Comment: did you get ur answer.?  I am facing the same problem

Comment: I have not found an answer sadly. I had to move on from ruby in this case but would love to know if there's a way.

Comment: no luck with windows. I am using rubyWMQ within a ubundu VM and now I don't face any problems.

Comment: Have the same issue. Works for me with Ruby v. 2.3.1, does not work with 2.5.1, either x86 or x64.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this by adding `C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin64` to my user `$Path`.

Which was odd, because `bin` and `bin64` had both been added to the System `$path` variable by the IBM install.

(This is with a mingw ruby install)